# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.sub_category_id' in 'where clause' -- Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have two tables categories and subcategories and I want to show the category with their connected subcategories. For this I have created a query. It shows an error when I try to fetch a category name from a category table using one to many relationships.

The tables are structured as
categories; id, name
subcategories: id, category_id, subname

```
// Category.php model   
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = "categories";

    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategory');
    } 
}

// Subcategory.php model       
class SubCategory extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
   protected $table = "subcategories";

     public function category()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
     } 
}

// Category Controller
public function show()
{     
    $categories=  Category::all();
    $subcategories=Subcategory::all();
    return view('show',compact('categories','subcategories'));
}

// show.blade.php
@foreach($subcategories as  $subcategory)
    {{ $subcategory->subname }}
    {{ $subcategory->category_id }}
    {{ $subcategory->category->name }}
@endforeach
```

This line is giving me error `{{ $subcategory->category->name }}`.

Comment: How does your abstraction work? How does it come from `SubCategory` to `sub_category`.

Comment: i dont understand your point.

Comment: Please post the Model class

Comment: Sir i have already post the model class as above.

Comment: I have sort this issue .In subcategory .php model i need to change hasmany to belongsTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to change hasmany to belongsTo

You are [right](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) because subcategory has only one category and you need use `belongsTo` relationship

```
class SubCategory extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = "subcategories";

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    } 
}
```